# Will my bitlocker partition be compromised if my Windows login is hacked

Tags: windows-7, encryption, bitlocker, tpm

I am thinking of turning on bitlocker on my 2nd external HDD which is physically connected to my laptop using one of the available bays.

For convenience i would like to allow the bit locker drive to be "remembered" on my laptop so i don't have to keep typing in the password.  The principal is the same as a portable USB drive.

With that in mind will my encrypted drive be exposed if someone hacks my Windows Login (brute force or whatever method)?  - In the event someone steals my laptop with the intent to see the data.

What role does the Trusted Platform Module (TPM Security chip) play? Can the TPM prevent this kind of hack?

Of course  all this can be prevented by turning off the remember feature but to have it off would be an inconvenience.

Comment: **Can the TPM prevent this kind of hack?** - No;For convenience i would like to allow the bit locker drive to be "remembered" on my laptop so i don't have to keep typing in the password.- You only have to type in the password if you unplug the device.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you decide to encrypt your device. You may use the TPM in which case you'll have to have a "PIN" or "Certificate" for the BitLocker encrypted drive.

Keep in mind all forms of encryption use some kind of "Key" either a "Certificate" or a "Password" these can reside on the laptop however if they can break into your laptop they have your keys.